# Checkout Android Billing API getPurchaseHistory method question

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Could you help to figure out what I'm doing wrong?
My goal is to obtain an Android subscription purchase history. To make this I using [Android-checkout](https://github.com/serso/android-checkout). So far the lib leverage was pretty straightforward. I managed to implement the purchase flow and access using

```
Inventory.Request
```

The next step in my business logic was to get a subscription history details.

Here is my code

```
 Billing billing = new Billing(this, new Billing.DefaultConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public String getPublicKey() {
            final Context applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
            final Resources resources = applicationContext.getResources();
            return resources.getString(R.string.google_play_key);
        }
    });
billing.connect()
billing.getRequests().isBillingSupported("<productId>")
```

isBillingSupported returns me BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE (2)

when I try the following

```
billing.getRequests().getPurchases(<productId>,
            null, new RequestListener<Purchases>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Purchases result) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int response, Exception e) {

                }
            });
```

The error callback method is returned and the error code is BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE (3)

Thanks in advance, probably it's worth getting switched to another library

Comment: You won't get the history of previous subscriptions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48116907/6657556).

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in the mentioned answer, there a reference to the  https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchaseHistoryResponseListener)   it says "Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed."